# CRUD with Angular + Ionic - Recursion, can't initialize data?

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been pulling my hair out over this for a bit now and I could use any help you can offer!

I'm trying to make an Ionic framework CRUD app with Angular (connected via PHP to MySQL, for what it's worth) and I've hit a problem - I can't get my list to seed the data.

My app has an index page and a few templates that comes in and out as needed. The default one is a list of items, and that's where I'm having the bother. I have a controller called membersController that's set in the ion-view for list, and I've tried to init the call to the server by putting ng-init="getRecords()" in the ion-view tag too, with getRecords() being the the $scrope in the controller that makes the call to the server to get the data. But it never gets called, and the console warns me about

"WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once."

I searched for this and it appears it can be a number of things, but commonly it relates to a recursive call because of a routing problem, I think? I've tried to diagnose it myself but honestly I've pretty green when it comes to Angular - I'm probably missing something basic!

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/toastr.js"></script>

<script src="js/jqueryScript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="snsApp">
    <ion-side-menus>
      <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
          <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon"></button>
          </ion-nav-buttons>
          <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>

        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
          <h1 class="title">SNS Menu</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/list">Members' List</ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/add">Add New Member</ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/visual">Send Notification</ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
  </body>
</html>
```

My app.js:

```
(function(){
// define application
app = angular.module("snsApp", ['ionic', 'components']);


app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider.state('list', {
      url: '/list',
      templateUrl: 'templates/list.html'
    });

    $stateProvider.state('add', {
      url: '/add',
      templateUrl: 'templates/add.html',
      controller: 'memberController'
    });

    $stateProvider.state('edit', {
      url: '/edit/:userId',
      templateUrl: 'templates/edit.html',
      controller: 'memberController'
    });

    $stateProvider.state('visual', {
      url: '/visual',
      templateUrl: 'templates/visual.html',
      controller: 'memberController'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/list');
});


app.controller("memberController", function($scope,$http){
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.tempUserData = {};
    // function to get records from the database
    $scope.getRecords = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/sns/action.php', {
            params:{
                'type':'view'
            }
        }).success(function(response){
            if(response.status == 'OK'){
                $scope.users = response.records;
            }
        });
    };



   // function to insert or update user data to the database
    $scope.saveUser = function(type){
        var data = $.param({
            'data':$scope.tempUserData,
            'type':type
        });
        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        };
        $http.post("http://localhost:8080/sns/action.php", data, config).success(function(response){
            if(response.status == 'OK'){
                if(type == 'edit'){
                    $scope.users[$scope.index].id = $scope.tempUserData.id;
                    $scope.users[$scope.index].name = $scope.tempUserData.name;
                    $scope.users[$scope.index].email = $scope.tempUserData.email;
                    $scope.users[$scope.index].phone = $scope.tempUserData.phone;
                    $scope.users[$scope.index].created = $scope.tempUserData.created;
                    $scope.users[$scope.index].group = $scope.tempUserData.group;
                }else{
                    $scope.users.push({
                        id:response.data.id,
                        name:response.data.name,
                        email:response.data.email,
                        phone:response.data.phone,
                        created:response.data.created,
                        group:response.data.group
                    });
                }

              //  $scope.userForm.$setPristine();
                $scope.tempUserData = {};
               // $('.formData').slideUp();
               // $scope.messageSuccess(response.msg);
            }else{
            //    $scope.messageError(response.msg);
            }
        });
    };

    // function to add user data
    $scope.addUser = function(){
        $scope.saveUser('add');
    };

    // function to edit user data
    $scope.editUser = function(user){
        $scope.tempUserData = {
            id:user.id,
            name:user.name,
            email:user.email,
            phone:user.phone,
            group:user.group,
            created:user.created
        };
        $scope.index = $scope.users.indexOf(user);
    };

    // function to update user data
    $scope.updateUser = function(){
        $scope.saveUser('edit');
    };

    // function to delete user data from the database
    $scope.deleteUser = function(user){
        var conf = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this member?');
        if(conf === true){
            var data = $.param({
                'id': user.id,
                'type':'delete'    
            });
            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }    
            };
            $http.post("http://localhost:8080/sns/action.php",data,config).success(function(response){
                if(response.status == 'OK'){
                    var index = $scope.users.indexOf(user);
                    $scope.users.splice(index,1);
                    $scope.messageSuccess(response.msg);
                }else{
                    $scope.messageError(response.msg);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    //function to remove user from list, then delete from the cloud database
    $scope.remove = function(userId){
        for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
          if(users[i].id == userId){
            users.splice(i, 1);
            $scope.deleteUser(users[i]);
            return;
          }
    };
  };
});


app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

        // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
        // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
        // a much nicer keyboard experience.
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      }
      if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  });
}());
```

My list.html:

```
init="getRecords()">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-icon-right" ng-repeat="user in users track by user.id">
        <i class="icon icon-left ion-{{user.email}}"></i>
        <h2 class="ion-{{user.email}}"> {{user.name}}</h2>
        <p> {{user.group}}</p>

        <a href="#/edit/{{user.id}}" class="button button-light icon ion-edit"></a>

        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive icon-left ion-trash-b" ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)">Delete</ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <br><br><br>
  </ion-content>
  <div class="bar bar-footer bar-stable">
      <div class="row">
          <a href="#/visual" class="col button button-balanced ion-android-add-circle left"> Send Notification</a> &nbsp;
        <a href="#/add" class="col button button-positive ion-person-add"> Add User</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: where is controller of state `list`?

Comment: Also check in network or console tab if `templates/list.html` exists

Comment: I used to have a dedicated list controller but when I hit this problem I tried to put it all into one controller to see if I could get it to work that way - that controller for list was declared on the list.html ion-view tag, and I replaced it with memberController - is that a problem? I've added it to the config and removed it from the ion-view and I still get the same message about Angular trying to load twice.

EDIT: list.html is in the network tab - what I get when I load the app is the list page, but without it ever loading any records.

Comment: `getRecords` is method of `memberController`. So your list.html must be using this controller

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps anyone in the future - issue was that ionic's bundle was bringing in Angular but I was still adding it separately in the scripts on the index page.